# Remove Wordpress News from dashboard and stop loading feeds

Tags: wordpress

I have been able to remove the widgets from the Wordpress dashboard that show Wordpress News using `remove_meta_box()`, but my database continues to get flooded with `_transient_feed` items that I do not need or want.  I can't seem to find where this is trigger, or how to turn it off.

**Note**

There are plenty of discussions about how to hide the meta boxes from the dashboard.  As I mentioned, I have already used `remove_meta_box()` for this purpose.  However, the data still appears in the the `wp_options` table, even after deleting.  I am using Wordpress as a CMS backend, so I want to reduce database usage with this garbage.

Comment: I used to look for this answer too, but found only solutions to delete the database of this record, but the records will be created again with new items. So I don't think there is a definite solution to this.

Comment: Please check this url "https://techubber.blogspot.com/2017/07/how-to-disable-or-hide-wordpress-default-widget-dashboard.html".

Answer (score 0):

I am experimenting with removing the following filter

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_widgets', 99 );
   function remove_widgets() {
     remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts-index.php', 'wp_localize_community_events' );
}
```

I will report back if this is successful or if there are other filters that also need to be removed